# Check for error in Spring JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a simple logic which print a message when error occured :

```
<form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error" />
<span id="username.errors" class="error">username is required!</span>
```

My question is: Is there any way to write if statement and if an error actually occured to make some checkbox checked which will open additional content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever there's an error caught in the spring controller. You could set a field in a model indicating the state of result i.e whether there was an error or not.

```
 if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("errorOccured", "true");
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("errorOccured", "false");
        }
```

Then in your JSP you could you can check the field for condition and change for html content accordingly like :

```html
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${errorOccured=='true'}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked>I have a car
    <br>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car
    <br>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```